# Filter a Report based on user input

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a report template which I want to open a single page report based on a specific IDENT NO. All of the fields in the report are then generated from the associated IDENT NO.

Currently, when I open the report, it will create a single page report for each ID number in the Report Data table when opened.

Instead, when the user is attempting to open the report, I want to prompt the user to enter the identification number of the specific report they are looking for so that it only opens that single individual 1 page report associated with the entered IDENT NO.

How could I achieve this filtering?

Comment: Prior to opening the report, you'll need to pop up a modal form and ask the user for the IDENT NO.  Then, after the user has entered that number, you'll need to re-set the *source* of the report.  Instead of "Select * from MyQuery", set it to "Select * from MyQuery where IDENT_NO = " & MyPopupForm.MyText.Text & ""

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display an InputBox for the user to insert the ID and then open and filter the report.

```
Dim id As String
    id = InputBox("Enter the identification number:", "YourInputBoxTitle")

'if a value was entered, open and filter report
If Len(Trim(id)) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , "[IDENT NO] = " & id, acWindowNormal
End If
```

Comment: Would this code go in the "On Load" Event in the Property Sheet for the Report?

Comment: After Running this Code and entering the Identification number in the text box, I get a runtime error 3270 - property not found. Any idea why this issue is occurring?

Comment: No it doesnt go there, it's usually placed on the Click event of a button in a form. How do you open he report?

Comment: You need to change the _ReportName_ to the name of your report and the _[IDENT NO]_ to the name of the id field. I presume it's a number, yes?

Comment: I open the report by clicking the report in the "All Access Objects" sidebar. Additionally, I have changed the ReportName to it's actual name, however I am unsure about the specific name of the [IDENT NO] since I didn't create this report, but was just tasked to create the filter for it. IS there a place where I can find the actual name for the [IDENT NO]?

Comment: If you open the report directly from "All Access Objects", you cannot use this. See, when you open the report, you need to provide a condition for the data to be filtered. This is usually done through an ID field e.g. 'ID = 1'. Do you have access to the report's query/recordsource?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the reports as well as all of the tables and query's. So I have been given access to everything, and my goal is to build the functionality of prompting a user for the Identification number they are looking for, and providing them with that single report.

Comment: I would suggest to build a simple form with a textbox and a button. The user enters the ID in the textbox and clicks the button. The report then opens filtered to the value entered in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `InputBox` is to use a "parameter query" (documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356))

Anywhere in a query criteria or report design view you may enter `[IdentNoVariable]` and a dialog box will appear (when the report or query is run) asking you to "Enter Parameter Value" for IdentNoVariable.

For example, if you wanted to restrict an ID # during a query (say the query that your report calls):

[image]

The dialog box seen appeared upon running the query and has the text of the variable seen in the query criteria. This same thing can be done in a report by entering `[IdentNoVariable]` into the part of the report where the entered value is desired.