# Placing an undeclared variable in SQL query code generates an input box?

Tags: sql, ms-access, user-input

I recently posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58740194/11715606) as a way to get user input when creating a MS Access query or report. The general behaviour is that if an undeclared variable is placed in SQL query code or a report (e.g. `[UndeclaredVariable]`), a small input/dialog box appears for the user to input the variables value.

I have been unable to find any mention of this functionality in documentation or elsewhere. All discussion is about using `InputBox()` in the standard way.

This functionality is unexpected/unusual for several reasons:

- (In my limited knowledge) Using undeclared variables in MS Access generally causes an error
- The input/dialog box is different than the one created when `InputBox()` is used
- The functionality seems to transcend standard behavior (e.g. when an two undeclared variable are used in this way as the "ifTrue" and "ifFalse" components of an `IIf()` statement, BOTH dialog boxes are created sequentially!)

Does anyone know what this functionality is called or why it works in these ways?

Comment: [MS Access query parameters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356)

Comment: goggle search for "ms access parameter user input" first result -> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed

Comment: Ok, ```parameter``` seems to be the keyword. Any insight to the behavior when combined with ```IIf()```. This seems quite odd.

Comment: `iif` will always evaluate **both** the `then` & `else` arguments before returning the appropriate argument depending on the outcome of the test expression - refer to the remark in the documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

Comment: VBA `IIf()` will always evaluate both the `then` & `else` arguments.  However Access SQL `IIf()` behaves differently.  (It's unfortunate that those functions share the same name.)  Access SQL `IIf()` will "short-circuit", meaning that when the "condition" is True, the "truepart" (`then`) argument is evaluated, and the "falsepart" (`else`) is not evaluated.

Comment: Hi @HansUp. If I understand what you are saying, my experience disagrees with this. If I include ```IIf(1=1, [iftrue], [iffalse])``` in the SQL view of an Access query (this is what you mean by Access SQL correct?), both parameter input boxes still appear sequentially (although I understand only the value input into "iftrue" will be returned).

Comment: @johnDanger When Access spots a parameter in your query, it will not execute the query until after it has received the parameter value.  Makes no difference where the parameter is used (or even not used) within the query --- Access still wants a value for the parameter.

Comment: In this query, I declare a parameter which is not actually used by the query: `PARAMETERS MyString Text ( 255 );
SELECT Dual.*
FROM Dual;`  Access still requires me to supply a value for `MyString` before running the query.

Comment: Or another example, closer to yours: `SELECT Dual.*, IIf(True,"T",[MyString]) AS Expr1
FROM Dual;`  Access still demands a value for `MyString` even though the `IIf` "falsepart" does not get evaluated when the query runs.

Comment: I see... this also occurs with ```IIf(True, [MyString]="T", [MyString]) so I guess there is no way to conditionally only open the dialog box (the original problem was to only open the dialog box if an associated text box was left empty). Thanks @HansUp! I will summarize these comments as an answer.

Comment: Parameters in a query is MASSIVE, HUGE, LARGE and a spectacular difference then  that of declaring  variables in VBA. So your assertions about declaring variables (for VBA) and that of parameters in a SQL query are 100% unrelated. Parameters in Access have rather little to do with variables that you declare in VBA code.  For reports, and most queries, you really don't need nor want to use sql parameters. So setup a form and user can enter values for criteria. You can then pass a where clause to the report. As such, any filter or criteria  for a report is optional and without parameters.

Comment: The question is not about parameters in a query, rather how MS Access deals with   / executes the parameterizing. This certainly could differ from standard SQL behavior.

Comment: Understood, but you stated <<Using undeclared variables in MS Access generally causes an error>>. So you asked and talked and spoke about variables - not parameters which are vastly different as i stated. I just posted a answer that will shed light on query  parameters in Access. They are NOT usually hard coded into the sql, but some approach to add criteria on the fly is used. See my answer below as to how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the above comments:

- the behavior is called a "parameter query" and is like normal parameterized queries (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356))
- The behavior with `IIf()` is because Access requires a parameter to be given whether or not the value is used (in this case for both [ifTrue] and [ifFalse])
- There seems to be no way to conditionally parameterize a query or report

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as to why they work the way they do? Well a lot of people use  Access for just working with data tables. They don't necessary build forms and reports. So, if you place a [parm] box in a query, it will prompt you, and you  don't need code. So, a really handy feature.

And of course if you do build a report, and need a quick and dirty way to prompt for some criteria then once again, super handy, and again no code or forms need be written.

And if you do create a form, then you can place criteria in a query like this:

select * from tblCustomers where City = Forms!MyPromptForm!City

once again, no code. And using a forms! expression like above means no prompt when you run the query (or a report based on that query).

The only real downside of using  these parameters is they are not without  effort to make them optional.

As you are finding out, putting forms! expression in queries can get really messy real fast. And such queries can prompt you when you don't want to.

Even worse, is now that the query is now "married" and attached to that ONE form (if you use forms! expressions for parameters).  Often, I have a nice query that I could use MANY times for different reports, and often even that same query could be used for reports...but then someone comes along and puts in a expression or paramter(s) that means the query is ONLY good when that form is opened, or you get nasty prompts for some parameter that you now don't want. Or you want DIFFERENT criteria on a different column.

So hard coding the number of parameters in such a query is REALLY painful, not flexible, and really starts to fall down.

So, if you have 5 combo boxes on a form, but the user only selects restrictions in 3 of the combo boxes...and wants the other 2 to be ignored?

I could probably write another 10 or pages as to why putting forms expressions in queries or shoving in parameters  is bad (besides...it makes the queries real ugly, and hard to read. and, the sql then is not standard anymore (it will not work with server based systems either).

So, the solution use now is simply to take the values from the form, and build your own where clause in code. That way, you simply design the reports (or forms), and attached them to the query, BUT NO FORMS! conditions are placed in the query. And the SQL is clean without garbage in it.

To "send" the conditions to the report (or form), you simply use the "where" clause. This is exactly why ms-access has this feature…and it solves a zillion problems…and will reduce your development costs by a substantial amount.

Take a look at the following screen shots to see what I mean:

[image]

So in above we have a start date, and end date. And the user can select 1, or several tours and THEN click on the report view button. Trying to deal with a easy and clean "prompt" form for user and THEN attempt to use a query with parmaters is sheer folly.

The code to make those above screens work and launch the report with the selected restrictions when you hit the "print" button is easy:

Or take this screen:

[image]

So in the above we have a combo box to select the sales rep.

But, you can leave it blank.

So, code to deal with above  will work like this:

```
dim   strWhere       as string

 'select sales rep combo

if isnull(cboSalesRep) = false then

   strWhere = "SalesRep = " & cboSalesRep & ""

end if

' select "status" for the report

if isnull(lstStatus) = false then
   if strWhere <> "" then
     strWhere = strWhere " and "
   end if
   strWhere = strWhere & "Status = '" & litStatus & "'"
end if
```

Note how the 2nd list box is checked for a value. You can add as "many" more conditions you want. Lets say we have a check box to only include Special Customers. We can add to our very nice prompt screen a check box to

[x] Show Only Special customers

The code we add would be:

```
if chkSpeicalOnly = True then
   if strWhere <> "" then
      strWhere = strWhere " and "
   endif
   strWhere = strWhere & "SpecialCust  =  true"
end if
```

For sure, each combo and control we add to the nice report screen takes a bit of code, but no more messy then the query builder..and this way, each query is nice and clean, and free of a bunch of HIGHLY un-maintainable forms! expressions or "optional" paramters.

Further, it means you can re-use the same query for different reports, and have no worries about some form that is supposed to be open or some nasty out of the blue prompt for a parameter. So, a tiny bit more code eliminates the messy query problem.. For me, this is very worth while trade.

So parameters are quick and dirty. But if REALLY going to start building a decent user interface and some nice report prompt forms? Dump the use of parameters - you be glad you did.  And you only have to go to the ONE  code spot, add another code block for a new and optional critera. You don't have to change the report, and and you don't have to go and modify the SQL either. So, a bit of code goes a LONG way to attacking this problem.

At the end of your code, we now have a valid SQL where clause. So, now just launch the report with with this:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "ReportName",acViewPreview,,strWhere
```

And the above also works for searching and launching a form. So the form can be based on such queries, and again no prompts or paramters means the form can be used to edit that data.

So the concept of filter data and launching forms (or reports) can and should be detached from the concept of some query that pulls data from a table. Over time, software will change, and then the boss will ask how about a filter or prompt for invoice number, but that again has to be optional. Over time your business rules will change. And you can often apply that filter to "many" reports. So in this form, the critea is built up, but the  list box allows you to select one of "many" reports, and not all are based on the same SQL, but they all accept the same "filter" or better term used is the "where" clause of the open report or form command.

[image]

In above, the user can hold down the ctrl-key to select 1 or 2 or hit the "select all" button. In that form, the user is actually selecting the bus tour ID for a given tour. And then they can choose the report in the lower left. Again, attempting to acheive the above multiple critera simply can't work with sql paramets anyway.

I am using a TourID = some value and Busid in (LIST OF buses selected).

once again, you can simply pass that complex "where" clause to the report - and that where clause can even have a sub-query, or a Field in (LIST OF ID'S) criteria (which can't be done with parameters anyway).